# The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server-2019

Since last week, one of our jobs started failing with this error:

> The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction

It's a stored procedure. It runs for more than 1hr then it aborts and displays the error above. It mostly tries to execute an `INSERT`.

I noticed that when the query runs we have a `CXCONSUMER` wait stats.

Also I noticed that, when I ran it manually, I could see on `sp_whoisactive` that the session I was using has `SID=50` for example, and on event viewer I see:

> Session 50 was killed by hostname

Nothing was changed and I'm failing to understand why. I saw some posts from *Brent Ozar* mentioning about setting `MAXDOP =1` and I'm going to test it, but for this problem, it's not the answer to what that error is.

Comment: What is the `Query Timeout` and `Connection Timeout` set to on your Linked Server object? Any chance the machine of the Linked Server changed in any way recently (specifically that would affect the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator settings)?

Comment: it's both set to 0. I noticed that the job normally runs for (on this step ) 40 minutes, and now its taking more than 1hr. yes probbly somewhere is hitting a timeout limit. but nothing was changed we are sure of it.

Comment: What is your MSDTC timeout set to?  `Start` -> `Run...` -> `comexp.msc` -> Expand `Component Services` -> Expand `Computers` -> Right-Click `My Computer` -> `Options` tab